# Trouble with bar chart Binary data

Tags: r, bar-chart, binary-data

I have the following data frame, from which i am trying to show the binary success of both group ID and treatment seperately:

The csv file below:

https://github.com/conda-suman07/Learn_Python/blob/612354f72caeb11d46719a9fc3280de3fb5f2c73/group_dataframe.csv

I want to create a bar chart/plot to shows the binary success of Group IDs' and treatment seperately. I am not quite sure how to do this when dealing with binary data and am hoping to get some assistance. I was thinking about loop over but not quite sure how to do that in R studio.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(tidyr)
 library(dplyr)
 library(gridExtra)
 library(binom)

#reading the csv file

group_data <- read.csv()

#creating the plot

bar_plot <-
  group_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= group_id, y=binary_success, fill= binary_success)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge", color='gray50', width=0.7) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
  bar_plot
```

but the code didnt work.

[image]